# Can't understand `sendInputEvent ` in webContents in ElectronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In Gmail, the shortcut of `compose` is `c`, and I use `forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'c'});` to call the feature `compose`, but it doesn't work, I should add  `keyUp` and `char`, and then it will works

```
forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'c'});
forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'char', keyCode: 'c'});
forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyUp', keyCode: 'c'});
```

Here are my questions

1. What does `char` stand for?
2. If I call `Go to Tasks` shortcut `g + k`, how should I update the code?

Thanks.

Updated: Here are full codes

```
 {
label: 'Edit',
submenu: [
  {
    label: 'Compose',
    accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+N',
    click(menuItem, forcedWindow, options) {
      if (forcedWindow) {
        forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'c'});
        forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'char', keyCode: 'c'});
        forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyUp', keyCode: 'c'});
      }
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

If I change the codes like this

```
{
label: 'Edit',
submenu: [
  {
    label: 'Compose',
    accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+N',
    click(menuItem, forcedWindow, options) {
      if (forcedWindow) {
        forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'c'});
      }
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

or like this

```
{
label: 'Edit',
submenu: [
  {
    label: 'Compose',
    accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+N',
    click(menuItem, forcedWindow, options) {
      if (forcedWindow) {
        forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'char', keyCode: 'c'});
      }
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

or like this

```
{
label: 'Edit',
submenu: [
  {
    label: 'Compose',
    accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+N',
    click(menuItem, forcedWindow, options) {
      if (forcedWindow) {
        forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyUp', keyCode: 'c'});
      }
    }
  }
 ]
}
```

none of them work, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sending manually from Electron we can emit the following events on the HTML page:

- `keydown`: Send `keyDown`
- `keypress`: Send `keyDown + char`
- `keyup`: Send `keyUp`

The `char` event representing that the key pressed contains character value to match the [description of `keypress` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress) in general.

> The keypress event is fired when a key that produces a character value
>   is pressed down. Examples of keys that produce a character value are
>   alphabetic, numeric, and punctuation keys. Examples of keys that don't
>   produce a character value are modifier keys such as Alt, Shift, Ctrl,
>   or Meta.

When pressing an alphabetic key on your keyboard it instantly produces `keydown` and `keypress` events, thus it's reasonable from a website to listen to `keypress` event (what Gmail seems to do)

To manually activate those listeners you should send `keyDown + char` at least. Here's an example for your cases

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.once('ready', () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow()
  win.loadURL('https://gmail.com')

  win.webContents.once('did-finish-load', () => {
    // Compose
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('compose...')
      win.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'c'})
      win.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'char', keyCode: 'c'})
    }, 1000)
    // Cancel Compose
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('cancel...')
      win.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'escape'})
      win.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'char', keyCode: 'escape'})
    }, 2000)
    // Go to Tasks
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('go to tasks...')
      win.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'g'})
      win.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'char', keyCode: 'g'})
      win.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'k'})
      win.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'char', keyCode: 'k'})
    }, 3000)
  })
})
```

*For the sake of completeness you should send `keyUp`s after every `keyDown + char` if you want to avoid emitting `keypress` for every subsequent `char`. But that's the minimum Gmail seems to be listening to.*

---

The relevant Chromium code if you're interested: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/public/platform/web_input_event.h

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track but in the [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendinputeventevent) for `sendInputEvent` it says the `keyCode` needs to be a valid accelerator key.

From the docs:

> `keyCode` String (required) - The character that will be sent as the keyboard event. Should only use the valid key codes in Accelerator.

And if you look at the [docs for accelerator](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/accelerator#available-key-codes) it says letters have to be upper cased.

So the `c` in your code would be upper cased like this:

```
forcedWindow.webContents.sendInputEvent({type: 'keyDown', keyCode: 'C'});
```

[`sendInputEvent` Docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentssendinputeventevent)

[Accelerator valid key codes](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/accelerator#available-key-codes)

Comment: Thank you, but let me make it clear, the lower case `c` is the shortcut in Gmail, not  in electronjs, I use `webContents.sendInputEvent` to send the `c` to Gmail Webview, please check my full codes in updates.